# file_get_contents, curl, wget fails with 403 response

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am trying to echo site data & for 95% of sites file_get_content, curl works just fine but for few sites, it never works whatever I tried. I tried to define proper user agent, changes SSL verify to false but nothing worked.

test site where it fails with forbidden https://norskbymiriams.dk/

wget is unable to copy ssl sites however wget is compiled with ssl support. checked with wget -V

i tried these codes.none worked for this particular site

```
file_get_contents

$list_url = "https://norskbymiriams.dk/";
$html = file_get_contents($list_url);
echo $html;


curl


$handle=curl_init('https://norskbymiriams.dk');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$content = curl_exec($handle);

echo $content;
```

any help will be great

Comment: Its simple HTTP status code 403 means you don't have access/permission to use/get it..

Comment: @AlwaysSunny its accessible from browser

Comment: @Steeve I think you are IP blocked (IP and a few more conditions since in browser it works). I tested exactly your code (the one starting with $handle line and it works perfectly good. I got 200 OK when I called it.

Comment: @besciualex is there anything we can whitelist our ip when the call is made from that site itself

Comment: @Steeve Honestly it depends solely on the politics of that site owner. I've seen examples of 403 Forbidden, with an error code attached, and also a message "if you think you got this error by a mistake from us, use this code, & contact us to unlock you'. Therefore there isn't a specific way to whitelist an IP. You should contact the site owner and ask for it. Or simply use a proxy to change your IP whenever 403 responses is detected by your script. :-)

Comment: @besciualex you are 100% correct.we were making request to that server without user agent and they might have detected scrapper so we have added user agent now onwards and asked that site to get the real reason for block so that we can know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some websites analyse a request extremely good. If there is a single thing that makes that  web server think you are a crawling bot, it might return 403.

I would try this:

1. make a request from browser, see all request headers, and place them in my curl request (simulate a real browser).
   [image]
2. my curl request would look like this:

> curl 'https://norskbymiriams.dk/'
>   -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1'
>   -H
>   'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100
>   Safari/537.36'
>   --compressed

Please try it. it works.

3. You can make a request in Chrome for example, and use Network tab from Developer tools to inspect a page request. If you right click on it, you will see **Copy as cURL**
   [image]
4. Therefore test each header separately in your actual cURL request, see which is the missing link, then add it and continue your crawling.